# Kubernetes a master turned into a minion?

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I was following [this guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/) for setting up Kubernetes on AWS.
At the end of the guide, I was running 1 master and 3 minions using AWS EC2 machines. Then I decided to shut them all off - thinking if the master is down, none will revive.

After few hours, I find 4 minions running.

Could it be the case that a master spawn up as a minion - somehow the order of operations caused this to happen?

How do I safely kill them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To safely shut down your cluster you should run `cluster/kube-down.sh` as described [at the end of the guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/#tearing-down-the-cluster) you linked to.

Comment: I also have terminated the server that spun up these monsters. :(